# Bash script on MacOS to delete current git branch and prune origin

Tags: bash, git, macos

Trying to write a bash script to put in my bash profile that deletes the current branch and prunes origin (intended for use after I've merged a remote pull request), with the following caveats:

1. Cannot delete master
2. requires a `-f` flag if the working branch is not clean OR where a -D flag would normally be required by git to successfully delete a branch.

The problem I'm hitting is that the `-f` flag isn't being picked up.

```
function deleteCurrentBranch() {
  branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')

  echo -e "Current branch is '$branch'"
  if [ $branch == "master" ]; then
    echo "This script cannot be used to delete the master branch!"
    return 1
  fi

  while getopts ":f" opt; do
     case ${opt} in
       f) 
          echo -e "Using the force!\n"
          force=true
          ;;
      *)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    esac
  done

  echo "Using the force? $force"

  if [ $force == true ]; then
    echo -e "git reset --hard\n"
    git reset --hard
  else
    if [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
      force=false
    else
      echo -e "Working directory not clean and not using the force, exiting"
      return 1
    fi
  fi

  echo -e "git checkout master\n"
  git checkout master

  echo -e "\ngit pull"
  git pull

  deleteCommand="git branch -"
  if [ $force == true ]; then
    deletecommand+="D"
  else
    deleteCommand+="d"
  fi

  deleteCommand+=" $branch"
  echo -e $deleteCommand
  eval "$deleteCommand"

  echo -e "\ngit remote prune origin"
  git remote prune origin

  return 0
}
```

Edit: I've spent a good amount of time on this tutorial page trying to figure this out
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Comment: What do you mean not picked ? Does getopt always output "Invalid option" ? Does getopt successfully detects you are using the `-f` flag but your `if` test fails afterwards ?

Comment: Well up until a few minutes ago, force was always set to false.  Currently, force is always true even if I don't supply the flag

Comment: not clear what changed

Comment: Why do you think this processing will be different on macOS from any other Unix-based platform?

Comment: I don't, necessarily, just providing more information in case it's relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you define `$force` outside of the `deleteCurrentBranch()` function?

If not, `$force` will be empty, the `if` statement (`if [ $force == true ]`) will be read like so;

`if [ == true ]; then`

This will fail. You could solve this by adding a default value `force=false` so it can't be empty, or you should add `"` around the `$force` variable. This way, bash always sees a (empty) string:
`

```
function deleteCurrentBranch() {
  # Default
  force="false"

  branch=$(git branch | sed -n -e 's/^\* \(.*\)/\1/p')

  echo -e "Current branch is '$branch'"
  if [ "$branch" == "master" ]; then
    echo "This script cannot be used to delete the master branch!"
    return 1
  fi

  while getopts ":f" opt; do
     case ${opt} in
       f) 
          echo -e "Using the force!\n"
          force=true
          ;;
      *)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    esac
  done

  echo "Using the force? $force"

  if [ "$force" == "true" ]; then
    echo -e "git reset --hard\n"
    git reset --hard
  else
    if [ -z "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
      force=false
    else
      echo -e "Working directory not clean and not using the force, exiting"
      return 1
    fi
  fi

  echo -e "git checkout master\n"
  git checkout master

  echo -e "\ngit pull"
  git pull

  deleteCommand="git branch -"
  if [ "$force" == "true" ]; then
    deleteCommand+="D"
  else
    deleteCommand+="d"
  fi

  deleteCommand+=" $branch"
  echo -e $deleteCommand
  eval "$deleteCommand"

  echo -e "\ngit remote prune origin"
  git remote prune origin

  return 0
}
```

Comment: whoops.  That got farther, but not quite there

Comment: The echo of the delete branch command is printing "git branch - test"

Comment: ahha! Found the remaining issue - on the line deletecommand+="D", it should be deleteCommand+="D" - mis-capitalized it!  Ugh.  I also wrapped all the "true" and "false" values in double quotes, and quoted $force wherever I referenced it.

Comment: I'm going to take the liberty to update your answer with the final, working version of my script and mark this as the right answer